# get the value of radio button by clicking on submit

Tags: jquery, laravel

When I will click on 'select' I will get the value of selected radio button but when I click on it the alert window comes blank 
html part:

```
<div id="cams_option" class="form-row form-group">
                            <table>


                                <tr>
                            <td><label class="col-md-11">
                                <input type="radio" name="cams1" id="cams1" value="1">&nbsp;<b>I Have Business in CAMS
                            </b></label></td></tr>
                            <tr>

                            <td><label class="col-md-11"><input type="radio" name="cams2" id="cams2" value="2">&nbsp;<b>I Don't Have A Business in CAMS</b></label></td>

                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                            <td><label class="col-md-11"><input type="radio" name="cams3" id="cams3" value="3">&nbsp;<b>I Will Update It Later</b></label></td>

                            </tr>


                            <tr>
                                <td><button class="btn btn-danger" id="cams_select">Select</button></td>
                            </tr>


                            </table>

                            </div>
```

And this is the Jquery Part:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                            $(document).ready(function()
                                {
                                    $('#cams_select').on('click',function()

                                    {
                                        var chk = $("#cams_option").val();

                                        alert(chk);
                                    })
                                });
                        </script>
```

Any Help will be very much appriciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to get the value of a div. You will need to get the value of the actual radio button that is selected.

Since all the radio buttons have different names, they can all be selected. You can get the value of each radio button by using the following:

```
var radio1 = $("#cams1").val();
```

However, you will need to know if it is checked or not. You can find that out by using:

```
var radio1checked = $("#cams1").is(":checked");
```

Putting it together, you can use:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#cams_select').on('click',function(){
    if($("#cams1").is(":checked")){
      var cam1 = $("#cams1").val();
      alert("Cam1 is checked: " +cam1);
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

You can repeat the code above to find out what is selected and getting the value of it based on your IDs set.

--Edit--
If you update the names of all 3 radio buttons to `name="cam"` only one of them can be selected. You can get the value of the selected cam by using the jQuery:

```
var selected = $("input[name='cam']:checked").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use all radio buttons with the same name , like "cams1".
and change the chk to :

```
var chk = $("input[name=cams1]:checked").val();
```